# Multiple conditional operator

Tags: java

I am familiar with Multiple conditions in ternary conditional operator like this:

```
( condition A ? value A :
  ( condition B ? value B : 
    ( condition C ? value C :
       ...
    )
  )
)
```

but I cannot understand how the code below works (function suppose to return an integer:

```
return (co1.Nr() < co2.Nr() ? -1 :
         ( co1.Nr() == co2.Nr() ? (co1.Id() < co2.Id() ? -1 : 
          (co1.Id() == co2.Id() ? 0 : 1)) : 1;
```

Will you please explain me?

Comment: These kinds of expressions are so hard to read. Fortunately with Java 8 you can write `Comparator.comparingInt(MyType::Nr).thenComparingInt(MyType::Id);`

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break it and understand. For ex: Consider the first part.

```
return (co1.Nr() < co2.Nr() ? -1 : (all_other_codes);
```

If the condition `co1.Nr() < co2.Nr()` true rerutn -1 else execute `all_other_codes`. Where as `all_other_codes` returns another `integer`.

Now look at `all_other_codes`

```
 ( co1.Nr() == co2.Nr() ? (co1.Id() < co2.Id() ? -1 : 
          (co1.Id() == co2.Id() ? 0 : 1)) : 1;
```

If `co1.Nr() == co2.Nr()` true return the value of

```
(co1.Id() < co2.Id() ? -1 : 
              (co1.Id() == co2.Id() ? 0 : 1))
```

else return `1`.

Answer (score 2):

That's a primary and secondary sort: order by Nr, and if they're equal, order by Id.  Returning -1, 0, and 1 is standard for comparison tests used for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

```
if co1.Nr() < co2.Nr() return -1
else if co1.Nr() == co2.Nr() then
    if co1.Id() < co2.Id() return  -1 
    else if co1.Id() == co2.Id() return 0 
    else return 1
else return 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition map to following

```
if(co1.Nr() < co2.Nr())
    return -1;
else if(co1.Nr() == co2.Nr())
    if(co1.Id() < co2.Id())
        return -1;
    else if(co1.Id() == co2.Id())
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
else
    return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically  this is what the code does with if's statements

```
if (co1.Nr()< co2.Nr()){
        return -1;
    }else if (co1.Nr()==co2.Nr()){
        if (co1.Id() <co2.Id()){
            return -1;
        }else if( co1.Id() == co2.Id()){
            return 0;

        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }else
    {
        return 1;
    }
```